# I can't make a button appear (possibly issue with static referencing)

Tags: android, reference

I want to make a button appear in the MenuActivity layout but the deciding if statement is in the CapitalReceiver class. I've tried adding 'static' to various variables but it didn't work. Please help!

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    String status;
    Boolean verified = false;
    String textColour = "#000000";
    TextView mTvCapital;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;  
     Intent mServiceIntent;
     CapitalReceiver mReceiver;
     IntentFilter mFilter;
     String country = "7ec47294ff3d8b74";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);   

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Button IDButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getIt);
        Button RefreshButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        long updateTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String updateTime = (String) DateFormat.format("hh:mm", updateTimeMillis);

        //If application has been submitted//
        if(preferences.contains("first_middle_store") & !(verified)) {
            status = "Status: Application pending. Last updated: " + updateTime;
            IDButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RefreshButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textColour = "#000000";
        }

        //If application has not been submitted
        else {
            status = "Status: Application not yet submitted";
            IDButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RefreshButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textColour = "#000000";
        }

        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.application_status);
        text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColour));
        text.setText(status);

        Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify);

      //Listening to verify event
              btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);
                }
              });

        Button btnNextScreen2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.how);

      //Listening to HowItWorks event
              btnNextScreen2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HowItWorksActivity.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen2);
                }
              });


      //Listening to IDbutton event
        IDButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IDActivity.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen3);
                }
              });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public  void refresh(View view) {
        // Getting reference to TextView 
        mTvCapital = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_capital);
        mTvCapital.setText("hello");

        // Creating an intent service
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CapitalService.class);

        mServiceIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_ANDROID_ID, country);

        // Starting the CapitalService to fetch the capital of the country
        startService(mServiceIntent);

        // Instantiating BroadcastReceiver
        mReceiver = new CapitalReceiver();

        // Creating an IntentFilter with action
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION);

        // Registering BroadcastReceiver with this activity for the intent filter
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, mFilter);

    }


    // Defining a BroadcastReceiver
    private static class CapitalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

            String capital = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_APPROVAL);

            if(capital == "YES") {

                //status = "Status: Application Approved";//
                //IDButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//
            }
            else if(capital == "NO"){

                //status = "Status: Application Denied";//

            }


        }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing over your code, a possible solution (and perhaps not the best) would be to make the ID Button variable global. You would then instantiate it in the onCreate whilst still allowing it to be manipulated in other classes in this MenuActivity. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry this is assuming that it is in fact the IDButton you are battling with currently (I was not sure based on your question)